# Unable to install ADT plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I did everything in Windows XP 32bit-with 4GB RAM, but thought why not install all applications on my other computer with 8GB RAM and Windows 7 loaded in it.
I installed everything (relevant 64-bit software : Java SDK-64 bit, Eclipse-64bit and Android SDK) in that Win 7-64 bit, except 1 thing in Windows 7 - 64bit. Even Android is loading fine on the emulator.

But when I am installing the ADT plugin in eclipse from **Help** > **Install New Software** > **https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/** then only 2 options are coming, and eventually the setup fails with showing the error that

> > Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.   Software being installed: Android Hierarchy Viewer
> >     16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
> >     16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)   Missing requirement: Android Hierarchy Viewer 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
> >     (com.android.ide.eclipse.hierarchyviewer.feature.group
> >     16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms 0.0.0' but it could not be found

I did everything correctly on Windows XP, but I am getting this problem on Win 7 - 64bit.
Can someone please let me know how to resolve this problem and successfully install the ADT plugin in Eclipse on Win 7 - 64 bit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ to http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ .

Comment: hey i tried both option but still thing plugin stuff is not getting installed with the following error:

Comment: hey i tried both option but still thing plugin stuff is not getting installed with the following error: `Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.` anybody can please help

Comment: This hasn't worked for me. I keep getting the message "http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" . I receive the same message when I use the https version too. Any thoughts? Thanks.